# Url Rewrite Module Not Working When Browsed Too

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Why isn't this rule working when I go to a browser with the URL rewrite module?
It works on the regex tester with the url rewrite module.
I even put it at the top of all my rules.

Example url: `organizations/51/middle-tennessee-basketball-showcases-basketball-tournaments?page=1`

Rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Organization Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^organizations/(.*)-basketball-tournaments\?page=1$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="organizations/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should be as following:

```
<rule name="Organization Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^organizations/(.*)-basketball-tournaments$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^page=1$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="organizations/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

You should not check the query string (here `page=1`) in the `url` test but in the `conditions` section.

Comment: I honestly think they should rename `url` to `path` since it is really what it is...but hey, this module is still a very good one!